# Slincing a pandas MultiIndex dataframe by one index where two row index value exist

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if anyone could please offer some advice:

I have a data set with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create individual pandas DataFrame.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Col2': [99, 98, 95, 90]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2], 'Col2': [99, 98]}, index=['A', 'B'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [3, 4], 'Col2': [95, 90]}, index=['C', 'D'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [3, 4], 'Col2': [95, 90]}, index=['B', 'C'])

# Combine into one multi-index dataframe
df_dict = dict(obj1=df1, obj2=df2, obj3=df3, obj4=df4)

# Assign multi-index labels
mDF = pd.concat(list(df_dict.values()), keys=list(df_dict.keys()))
mDF.rename_axis(index=["ID", "property"], inplace=True)
print(mDF, '\n')
```

These multi-index dataframes have different number of "property" rows:

```
               Col1  Col2
ID   property            
obj1 A            1    99
     B            2    98
     C            3    95
     D            4    90
obj2 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj3 C            3    95
     D            4    90
obj4 B            3    95
     C            4    90
```

For example, I would like to calculate the sum of Col1 values for property A and B or all "IDs". However, this is only possible for those "ID" which have both properties tabulated.

I have tried to use the `isin` and `query` attributes:

```
idcs_isin = mDF.index.get_level_values('property').isin(['A', 'B'])
idcs_query = mDF.query('property in ["A","B"]')
print(f'isin:\n{mDF.loc[idcs_isin]}\n')
print(f'Query:\n{idcs_query}')
```

However, this returns any "ID" with either of the properties:

```
               Col1  Col2
ID   property            
obj1 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj2 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj4 B            3    95

Query:
               Col1  Col2
ID   property            
obj1 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj2 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj4 B            3    95
```

Which function should I use to recover the IDs "`obj1`" and "`obj2`" the only ones which have both the `A` and `B` properties?

Comment: can you explicit the expected output? what do you mean by *However, this is only possible for obj ID which have both properties tabulated.*? is it only when objID has both A and B or? are you looking for `mDF.loc[mDF.index.get_level_values('property').isin(['A','B']), 'Col1'].sum()` for example?

Comment: kindly provide the expected output dataframe

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T, I added your example to the question but I just noticed it does not work if you require both. Would you have another suggestion to add as a solution?

Comment: Thank you @sammywemmy I added a better example and the needed output. Do you have a suggestion for the solution?

Comment: what is the expected output dataframe @Delosari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to build a boolean array, which captures rows where both `A` and `B` exist per `ID`, and then use that array to index `mDF`:

```py
bools = mDF.index.get_level_values('property').isin(['A','B'])
grouper = mDF.index.get_level_values('ID')
# there should be a minimum of two (`A`, `B`)
bools = pd.Series(bools).groupby(grouper).transform('sum').ge(2).array
mDF.loc[bools]
               Col1  Col2
ID   property            
obj1 A            1    99
     B            2    98
     C            3    95
     D            4    90
obj2 A            1    99
     B            2    98
```

Answer (score 1):

Query works with named index:

```
mDF.query('property in ["A","B"]')
```

Output:

```
               Col1  Col2
ID   property            
obj1 A            1    99
     B            2    98
obj2 A            1    99
     B            2    98
```

Formatting the query string can be tricky sometimes. If you don't feel comfortable with it, you can use Ben.T's suggestion with `.index.get_level_values`.

Comment: Hello @Quang Hoang, I used your example on my code but I realized it did not work as expected. I have rewritten the example to make it clear I need the IDs which have both property rows. Do you think you could please review it?